Molecular stretching oscillations directions
Molecular stretching oscillations directions.
If we say that vertical oscillation is up/down. Then, left/right and front/back are horizontal oscillations.
Hence, when we measure oscillations of molecules, are they stretching horizontally and vertically?
In other words, where are the detecting laser beams positioned to capture the oscillations? Are the results equal in all axes?
